# What is the "path" mean in Django urls

Tags: python, django

When a read some new project on `Django` in one of `urls.py` files i find following code:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('buyers/embed/<int:id>/view', views.buyers_view),
]
```

This is written in application that not used for now (Instead of this is used another application for buyers view). But i want to know what is this `path`.

I can't find any information about it in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/).
Maybe this is some old style for `url` routing, or some mistakes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: path is a new function defined in **django 2.0** .It returns an element for inclusion in `urlpatterns` in `urls.py` .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/) is from the new URL syntax, which was [added in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax).

You can find out more information in the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view) or [url docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/), as long as you have Django 2.0 or later selected on the documentation site.

Comment: Since this answer is picked up by cht.sh, could you please update it with the relevant content? User this link as an inspiration https://consideratecode.com/2018/05/02/django-2-0-url-to-path-cheatsheet/

Comment: @Andy I've removed the out of date sentence about 2.0 being alpha. I'd rather link to the docs which gives a full explanation rather than trying to recreate that here.

Comment: okay, good point to not recreate the docs , but could you please link here instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/ ?

Comment: `path()` now links to that URL.

Answer (score 1):

`path()` Function Returns an element for inclusion in urlpatterns with 4 args: Two required route and view and two are optional kwargs and name

`path(route, view, kwargs=None, name=None)`